# Same MVC Partial View for DropdownListFor but specify different control ID

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is it possible to use the same Partial View more than once on a page to render a dropdown list with different IDs?

**I've created a Partial View:**

```
@model XXXX_Web_App.Models.LanguageListPartialViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedLanguage,
    Model.Languages,
    new { @class = "form-control" }
)
```

**It's included in _Layout.cshtml with:**

```
<form action="/Account/TestPartial" method="get">
    @Html.Action("LanguageListPartial", "Account")
</form>
```

**and renders as:**

```
<form method="get" action="/Account/TestPartial" novalidate="novalidate">
    <select name="SelectedLanguage" id="SelectedLanguage">
        <option value="en-US" selected="selected">English</option>
        <option value="fr-CA">Français</option>
        <option value="pt-BR">Português</option>
        <option value="es-MX">Español</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Changing the selection in the header fires a jQuery function in _Layout.cshtml:**

```
<div id="test" class="hide"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#SelectedLanguage').on('change', function () {
            var culture = $(this).val();
            $('#test').load("/Account/LanguageListPartial/" + culture, function () {
                location.reload(true);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

All of the above is working fine, but I have a few pages where the same dropdown list is needed. For example, when the user registers for a new account or when an existing user needs to edit their profile. So I would like to include the dropdown list in these views which have their own `<form>` wrapper, like:

```
@Html.Action("LanguageListPartial", "Account")
```

Doing this causes two dropdown lists with the same ID and I understand why this is happening, of course. It breaks the jQuery.

My question: Is there a way of specifying the ID of a rendered control so that the Partial View can be used more than once on a page? My guess is no...

Or even if I need to create another Partial View, is there a way of specifying within the Partial View what ID I want the DropDownListFor to render the  instead of using the Model's ID so that I can use the same Controller Actions? Keeping in mind that the header's dropdown list does not perform a POST since it is only triggered by the jQuery. (I think that's the right way of explaining it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, specify different ids in route values whenever you create a partial view:

```
 @Html.Action("LanguageListPartial", "Account", 
               new {id=someid, selectedlanguage=language})
```

Change you action to

```
public ActionResult LanguageListPartial(string id, string selectedlanguage)
```

Inside the controller, assign value to viewbag,

```
 ViewBag.differentid=id;
```

and use it in you partial view as id.

```
 @model XXXX_Web_App.Models.LanguageListPartialViewModel

 @Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedLanguage,
    Model.Languages,
    new { id = ViewData["differentid"] }
 )
```

Comment: Oh nice, I wouldn't have thought it possible. So the id/name is set in ViewBag within the LanguageListPartial Controller Action, but how would the Controller Action distinguish what to set the ID to? I probably would leave the head dropdown the same all the time of course, but use a unique id in the few Views where it would be duplicated.

Comment: Got it. Neat! Thank you Danyu.

Comment: how is `new {droplistid = someid}` referenced in the controller action? I mean, `someid` is the value to store in ViewBag. And should `droplistid` actually be `differentid` in your example?

Comment: I need to create a new MapRoute for this, right? Thx.

Comment: Well, I should tell you why I ask that. In the Controller Action `droplistid` does not exist in the current context.

Comment: then define an argument for that action/function to hold droplistid. :)

Comment: :S Your code made it look so simple and I thought I understood how to implement it at first glance. I haven't given up trying to work it out, but that MapRoute is troubling me. Also, for accuracy, shouldn't the ViewData be ViewBag and shouldn't it be `ViewBag.differentid` instead of `ViewBag["differentid"]`?

Comment: You do not have to create a new route. I assume the default MapRoute has "id" as default argument, so you can do LanguageListPartial(string id). I will update the answer right away.

Comment: Even better, but the HttpPost Controller Action already has an argument with `string selectedlanguage` so this creates a conflict.

Comment: Multiple route values is not a problem, see the updated answer.